# Finding an optimal value for parameter given other parameters

Tags: r, regression, optimization, regression-coefficients

I am looking for a way to find an optimal value among several combinations of values.

The data looks like this:

```
  N      V    MDO   MLO   ERROR 
1231   50.0   4.0  0.010  0.143
131    10.0   8.0  0.002  0.150
1319   40.0   4.5  0.050  0.150
13410  20.0   9.0  0.025  0.146
5231   50.0   3.5  0.010  0.148
 ..     ..     ..   ..     ..
1231   50.0   6.0  0.050  0.144
```

I want to find the optimal values for:

- MDO given MLO, N, V that minimizes error.
- MLO given MDO, N, V that minimizes error.

The confusion for me is that it does not appear to be a linear problem.

For example:

```
error ~ MLO + MDO + N + V  (where MDO, N, V are control variables)
```

If you would try to interpret a coefficient for MDO then, e.g. if the coefficient would be negative (for each increase in MDO the error decreases), the conclusion would be "let's choose an infinite MDO". It might actually be in the middle.

So, what is the actual problem here and how can I try to find an optimal value?

Comment: If you have a definition for this problem that would be great. I would change the title to more accurately reflect the question.

Comment: "optimal" in what sense?

Comment: @Glen_b quoting myself: "I want to find optimal values for MDO given MLO, N, V, **that minimizes error** ..."

Comment: It's not clear what the optimization problem is. Are you - as it seems - trying to model the variable 'error' as a function of the other variables and identify the minimum? Is your data fixed or can you take additional observations (and get their error)? Can you talk about the characteristics of 'error' - is this a smooth problem or a combinatorial one? If smooth, is it unimodal?

Comment: @Glen_b I see your point. It is possible to get additional observations. The variables represent different hyperparameters, and associated with each combination is an error. Rather than using the values for which I find the lowest error, I'd actually like to try and predict which combination (not necessarily the one I sampled) would yield the lowest error. So yea, the error is also a function of the data. In fact, a sample of the data is taken. My idea here is to try and fit a model on low N (100-10,000), and try to predict what values should be used with N=100,000.

Comment: I see that this is not a simple prediction as there are other variables involved. I guess I'd like to approximate the values that would minimize the error at N=100,000.

Comment: You might like to look at [response surface methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Response_surface_methodology);  it might be of some relevance to you. You may wish to - and can - use more complicated models than is typical for RSM, but the overall ideas may help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define some sort of loss function that is a function of the parameters. Once you have defined your function as $f(MDO, MLO, N, V)$, then you have a simple minimization task that you can throw optimization routines at. Your two sub problems reduce to:

$$\widehat{MDO} = \underset{MDO}{\operatorname{argmin}}f(MDO; MLO, N, V)$$

and

$$\widehat{MLO} = \underset{MLO}{\operatorname{argmin}}f(MLO; MDO, N, V)$$

or if you're looking for the combination of parameters that minimizes your loss function over all parameters, you can do that to.

$$\beta = \{MLO, MDO, N, V\}$$

$$\hat{\beta} = \underset{\beta}{\operatorname{argmin}}f(\beta)$$

Comment: Could you give a suggestion of how to do do that / go forward, perhaps by an example?

Comment: Not really, no. I don't have enough context into your problem to tell you how to meaningfully define your loss function. You have a column in your data called "error." How is that being generated? If error is a function of the other variables, then whatever function you used to calculate "error" probably makes sense to use as your loss function.

Comment: RMSE was used to produce the errors. I'm not sure how to model "argmin". N represents sample size, V amount of variables.

Comment: RMSE relative to what? What's your response variable? How are you generating predictions? You haven't characterized your problem at all. Help me help you.

Comment: My initial X are pixels, I try to predict some probabilities for classes using RandomForest. I took some samples of size N on V variables and used to produce a cross validation error by modeling y~X. The MDO is max depth and the ML is min_leaf_size. RMSE was used to score.

Comment: I understand it might seem like a bad idea and perhaps not work, but still I would be interested in how to solve it theoretically...